# Disable tapping page scroll on iOS

Tags: ios, scroll, pspdfkit

PSPDFKit lets you scroll pages of a PDF 2 ways, by swiping left or right, or by tapping on the left or right edges. Is there a way to disable this "left or right" edges tapping?

We want to use PDF tapping for something completely different and this effect causes some issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PSPDFKit Founder here. Please use our support Platform at https://support.pspdfkit.com to ask questions.

Since this is an easy one, I'll reply here.

Simply disable [scrollOnTapPageEndEnabled](https://pspdfkit.com/api/ios/Classes/PSPDFConfiguration.html#//api/name/scrollOnTapPageEndEnabled).

Comment: Thanks, will post in the support forum in the future.